# array_unique outputs null while sorting array

Tags: php, arrays, array-unique

I have this array (decoded from JSON, output with print_r):

```
stdClass Object
(
    [data] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [item] => te
                    [date] => 13.10
                )
            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [item] => te
                    [date] => 13.10
                )
            [2] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [item] => tr
                    [date] => 13.10
                )
        )
)
```

But now I have to remove all the duplicates.
If I try `$result = array_unique($array, SORT_REGULAR);`
`$result` is null.

Can someone spot my mistake?

Comment: this is a standard object not an array, convert it in the array first

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a **stdClass** object, not an array. When you decode by using the function *json_decode*, you need to pass the parameter "true" to have an array:

```
$array = json_decode($json, true);
```

Edit: As people noticed in the comments, the actual array exists in `$array['data']`, so the `array_unique` must be applied on `$array['data']` instead of `$array`.

Comment: Maybe also add that after that the `array_unique` must be applied on `$array["data"]` instead of `$array`.

Comment: @trincot yeah, correct. the actual array exist in $array['data']. please update the answer

Comment: So, with the true parameter I can see the sorted array. But how can I get it back to original JSON with the data array?

Comment: @Francis You can use the `json_encode` function:  http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php